# Openlayers in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, openlayers, laravel-10

i want to add openlayers in laravel frameworks but it always have an error like this:

```
openlayers:1  Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "rbush". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

and another error is like this:
Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type
Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/css". Strict MIME type

can someone help me to fix and solve this so my openlayers and the map is shown webpage so the laravel frameworks is working after adding openlayers library?

thank you

solve this so my openlayers and the map is shown webpage so the laravel frameworks is working after adding openlayers library

Comment: How do you use this `openlayers`? Where do you get `Relative references` error? Post relevant code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: i just try to make the code like this:
// import '../css/style.css';
import Map from '../../node_modules/ol/Map.js';
import OSM from '../../node_modules/ol/source/OSM.js';//ol/source/OSM
import TileLayer from '../../node_modules/ol/layer/Tile.js'; //ol/layer/Tile
import View from '../../node_modules/ol/View.js';

like basic quick start in openlayers and uhhh the problem is the css map is not showing even the function is always error

Comment: please i need all of your help, perhaps we can share something we dont know about this.

your help means a lot be healthy guys

Comment: i just need to know how to start openlayers 9 into laravel 10 cause this is new for me to applying openlayers into laravel

Comment: For the module errors see OpenLayers issues such as https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/11935 and https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/14456